# Get the latest date for the launch package

Tags: ssis

Good evening.

I need to implement a package saves the last run. That would be when you run a package the data is appended and not overwritten (to select the same data).

I suspect that I need to use a stored procedure to capture the data.

Comment: This question is very general.  We need more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is your goal to have your package only process new data? For example, every time the package runs, it should start pulling data from the source where it left of during the previous run?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run an incremental load which loads only the differences since the previous load where differences include New rows, Updated rows, Deleted rows? if yes then the article linked below will be very, very helpfull.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/75331/